# app_engine_apis: true not appearing in deployed version's config

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

i'm trying to deploy a go API on the 116 runtime that requires task queues. Upon accessing the endpoint that utilizes task queues, the log tells me: `please add app_engine_apis: true to your app.yaml to enable`. I've added it in my app.yml (see below) but it does not appear in the final configs for the version in the console. Any ideas?

edit: for clarity, in this screen I attempted toggling to the go115 runtime, but the same issue exists for both runtimes

[image]
[image]

Comment: did you use `gcloud beta`? Also, did you test your app locally to check if the API services are working?

Comment: I did not, this was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given using the GAE services in 2nd Gen runtimes is still in Preview, visibility in the console probably just hasn't been implemented.  You can check if the setting has been applied using the [Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1beta/apps.services.versions/get), where `"appEngineApis": true` setting should be showing.

It also shows if you use [gcloud beta app versions describe](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/versions/describe) (make sure to include `beta`).